# The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint inside init with frame initializer

Tags: ios, swift

I have a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`:

```
class MonthPlanCollectionViewCell: FSCalendarCell {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.alignment = .center

        stackView.addArrangedSubview(dayLabel)
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        dayLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        plannedTimeLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        contentView.addSubview(stackView)

        let leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let trailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let centerY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        stackView.addConstraints([leading, trailing, centerY])
    }
}
```

This class is used like this:

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, cellFor date: Date, at position: FSCalendarMonthPosition) -> FSCalendarCell {

    let cell = calendar.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MonthPlanCollectionViewCellIdentifier, for: date, at: .current) as! MonthPlanCollectionViewCell


    return cell
}
```

But everytime I have following issue:

> 2017-10-03 20:12:31.175147+0200 FieldService[9098:2747076] [LayoutConstraints] The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: id: , constant: 0.0
>       When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
>   2017-10-03 20:12:31.176687+0200 FieldService[9098:2747076] [LayoutConstraints] View hierarchy unprepared for constraint.
>       Constraint: id: , constant: 0.0
>       Container hierarchy: 
>   >
>      | >
>      | >
>      | >
>       View not found in container hierarchy: ; layer = >

What to do to make that view prepared for hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

Try to first add constraints and then call contentView.addSubview(stackView)

Comment: if not that the only thing left is to add those constraints on parent not on stackView,( contentView.addConstraints)

Comment: o, I try. Make constraints active?

Comment: NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true or leading.isActive = true

Comment: you can find more details on apple pages https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the StackView's constraints either to `self` or to the `contentView`.

Just change:

```
stackView.addConstraints([leading, trailing, centerY])
```

to:

```
contentView.addConstraints([leading, trailing, centerY])
```